# Xamarin iOS OidcClient requires HTTPS (possible by App Transport Security)

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to connect to an IdentityServer (V4) without SSL but that occurs a crash on my Xamarin iOS Application.

Code:

```
OidcClient _client;
AuthorizeState _state;
SafariServices.SFAuthenticationSession _session;

public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{

    var options = new OidcClientOptions
    {
        Authority = "http://auth.xxxx.be",
        ClientId = "iosClient",

        Scope = "openid email xxx",
        RedirectUri = "xxxApp://callback",

        ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,

    };

    _client = new OidcClient(options);

}
```

When the code is executed, i get the following error:

```
Error loading discovery document: Error connecting to 
http://auth.xxxx.be/.well-known/openid-configuration: HTTPS required
```

I tried to allow non-https requests with the following lines

```
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
     ...
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</dict>
    </plist>
```

But this has no effect. Possibly because the OidcClient used his own methods to connect to this web application.

Offcourse with SSL, this is not a problem but I want to save some costs to run my website on Azure (= higher cost for SSL support).

I'm running the latest Xamarin/Visual Studio with iOS 11.

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads should set to be true.

Comment: ooh i tried before to set it to true but didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use a browser to access your config?
`http://auth.xxxx.be/.well-known/openid-configuration`

If not, maybe your server is not setup correctly.  If its not your server, this should work:

```
 _options = new OidcClientOptions()
        {
            Authority = "your authority",
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "your scopes",
            RedirectUri = "redirectUrl",
            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,
            Policy = new Policy()
            {
                Discovery = new DiscoveryPolicy() { RequireHttps = false }
            }
        };
```

To avoid the crash, wrap it in a try catch and plan accordingly.